# .htaccess not ignoring a directory when applying rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Stuck on this one for a while before I turned for help, any assistance is appreciated.

For all intensive purposes I had to use this method to redirect all the lowercase URLS to work on my current setup, its not pretty I know.

The issue is when I use this setup all the Urls in the directory its supposed to skip  break. For example /dont-touch/File1 stops working - I need to insert the below code so the lowercase rewrites dont apply to /dont-touch

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/dont-touch/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/blog/"
RewriteRule ![A-Z] - [S=26]
RewriteRule ^(.*)A(.*)$ /$1a$2 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)B(.*)$ /$1b$2 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)C(.*)$ /$1c$2 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)D(.*)$ /$1d$2 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)E(.*)$ /$1e$2 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)F(.*)$ /$1f$2 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)G(.*)$ /$1g$2 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)H(.*)$ /$1h$2 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)I(.*)$ /$1i$2 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)J(.*)$ /$1j$2 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)K(.*)$ /$1k$2 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)L(.*)$ /$1l$2 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)M(.*)$ /$1m$2 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)N(.*)$ /$1n$2 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)O(.*)$ /$1o$2 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)P(.*)$ /$1p$2 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)Q(.*)$ /$1q$2 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)R(.*)$ /$1r$2 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)S(.*)$ /$1s$2 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)T(.*)$ /$1t$2 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)U(.*)$ /$1u$2 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)V(.*)$ /$1v$2 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)W(.*)$ /$1w$2 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)X(.*)$ /$1x$2 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)Y(.*)$ /$1y$2 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)Z(.*)$ /$1z$2 [R,L]
```

This is how my HTACCESS file looks, Ive tried putting it at the start... the end. Nothing works.

```
 RewriteEngine On



 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]


 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/component/
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/administrator/
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I have to admit I did a double take on this one: **For all intensive purposes**. For all intents and purposes?    I take it you're on an Apache server and changes to .htaccess _are_ being recognized and processed? Anyway, according to the answer below, you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you're better of using RewriteMap here:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap  lc int:tolower
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

This will change everything in the URI to lowercase, instead of 26 slow rules.

Secondly, for the directories not to be rewritten, I don't think you should put them in quotes

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dont-touch(/|$) [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog(/|$)
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
```

And if you put the `[L]` flag at the end, nothing below that point will interfere with this rule.

Comment: Right but doesnt the RewriteMap  
    lc int:tolower 
have to be in a httpd.conf or VHOST file. I dont have access.

Comment: Oh hmm, yes that declaration needs to go in the vhost or conf file. Once it's there though, you can use the map in .htaccess. Maybe your hosting provider has a map defined?

Comment: So I got access to the httpd and added the declaration right before the <virtual host/> end tag and the pages in question forawrd to /home/folder/public_html

Comment: Hmm in that case the Document Root is probably not set correctly.

Comment: Try setting `RewriteBase /` right after `RewriteEngine on`. Also, do you actually see `/home/folder/public_html` in the address bar of the browser?

Comment: Added the declaration under the wrong <Virtual Host> tag. Thanks Again